# Using BibTeX. Don't want it to use alphabetical order for multiple works within single year same author

Tags: bibtex

If a single author has more than one publication within a single year, BibTeX orders the references alphabetically by title.  But I would like to have them ordered by when they were actually published.  This is what BibTeX's giving me now:

Josh, Robert (2015a), ‘Names’, in A. Bianchi, ed., On Reference, Oxford University Press, pp. 225–250.

Josh, Robert (2015b), ‘Reference’, Erkenntnis 80(Supplement 2): 363–404.

Josh, Robert (2015c), ‘A Rejoinder’, in A. Bianchi, ed., On Reference, Oxford University Press, pp. 180–194.

But I want to exchange the order of the last two of these three entries.  I know how to edit the .bbl file once I'm done, but I want to know if there's a better way.

Comment: is the exact date in the bibfile?

Comment: Oh, no.  I'll try that.  Do you mean filling in the "month" field?  I'm using agsm.bst with harvard.sty

Comment: You can use date={YYYY-MM-DD}

Comment: @MaxNoe No, You can't. Not unless you are using Biblatex. Traditional bibtex with `\bibliographystyle` etc. does not know about `date` and will simply ignore the field.

Comment: I don't think that filling in the additional details of the date will help. Standard bibliography styles order by year rather than date. If you are not using Biblatex, you can use `key` to specify something to sort by, and so override the default sorting order. If you are using Biblatex, you can use `key` or `sortkey` and there are some other options as well, although I doubt anything will sort by month or day out-of-the-box just because that isn't a usual thing to do ;).

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't want to imply that. I just wanted to know if the information is there to provide a solution using it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to trick bibtex  into thinking that a article title starts with a "z"?